# Angular Universal CSS imports not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-universal

I'm just testing out how Angular Universal handles the imports of third party JavaScript and CSS libraries. For ease of use I tried with jQuery and Bootstrap.

I'm using the Universal Starter repo https://github.com/angular/universal-starter and installed jQuery and Bootstrap through npm.

In my `app.component.ts` I included jQuery like so and it works perfectly.

```
import { isBrowser, isNode } from 'angular2-universal'
var jQuery: any = require('jquery');

...

@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'ftw';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (isBrowser) {
      jQuery('#universal').css({'color': '#FF0000', 'font-size': '25px'})
    }
  }
}
```

Though when I want to import a css file it won't work properly. I'm importing it within my `app/client.ts` file as follows.

```
...
// Angular 2
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformUniversalDynamic } from 'angular2-universal/browser';
import { bootloader } from '@angularclass/bootloader';

import { load as loadWebFont } from 'webfontloader';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

// enable prod for faster renders
enableProdMode();
...
```

The actual Bootstrap css is within my Webpack bundle but my HTML isn't styled in any way. Anybody had a similar problem with this and knows how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';` work, you'll need [style loader](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader), which is not installed with universal-starter repo. Sidenote: If you use bootstrap.css as is, and you want to use universal-starter, you can copy bootstrap.min.css into assets folder and add a link tag for it in index.html.

Comment: My intentions are to include Clarity from VMWare https://vmware.github.io/clarity/ but I was trying to include bootstrap first to try it out. I prefer to directly import the files through webpack for when the package might be updated in the future. I'm trying the style-loader for now but without any success yet. Webpack compiles but running the server crashes. Getting the `TypeError: cssText.replace is not a function` error for now. My code is `{
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader' })
      }`

Comment: As far as I know, you'll need two sets of loaders: for [css in componets](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js#L130), and for [css with imports](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.dev.js#L99). I myself need to try it out.

Comment: I'm trying this out as we speak, I'll notify you if I make any progress

Comment: I could not make it work. [Here](https://github.com/rxjs-space/try-universal-starter/commit/c2e08de1c02e854c160452e027bf2c9338fb6f93) are the files I changed. After `npm start`, the external css file was already generated under `dist/client`, but it just won't be served. Frankly, I'm too reliant on angular-cli, where all such build work are done for free.

Comment: Haven't been able to get it working myself either unfortunately. I'm going to read the docs for for webpack and try and come up with a solution because I really need it. Wish there was a universal cli available already.

Comment: There's one, [universal-cli](https://github.com/devCrossNet/universal-cli), but I don't suggest you to use it in production at the moment, because: 1)  universal itself is undergoing big changes, it would be merged into the '@angular' domain, possibly available two month later; and for the same reason, further development of universal-cli is stuck. 2) universal-cli is not developed by angular core team, there would be delay when you want to use latest features, for example, aot and hmr are still under development for universal-cli. [ref](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12495)

Answer (score -1):

Go to the angular-cli.json or angular.json file at the root of your Angular CLI project folder, and find the scripts: [] property, and include the path to jQuery as follows:

```
"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"]
```

Now, to use jQuery, all you have to do is to import it in whatever    component you want to use jQuery.

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
(or)
declare var $: any;

import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit()
  {
    $(document).ready(function(){
       // your code
    });
  }
}
```